# Loading GeoChart markers asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a Google Visualization for a GeoChart. It loads the markers and colorizes/sizes them correctly. It seems, however, to "geocode" each marker one at a time. This appears to make a pair of requests per marker, as shown in this image.

[image]

My issue is that this is very slow. I am creating two charts on this page. One for the `US` region and one for the `CA` region. When drawing the visualization it appears to queue up these geocode requests. This means that the US map (loaded first) will start drawing markers but CA will not until US is completely finished. The US map has 413 markers to be drawn, this takes a **long** time.

What am I missing to make this faster or perform these request asynchronously?

Currently the callback being triggers for onLoad is as follows. I call the same function on the second chart when switching between the two.

```
function drawMarkersMap(region) {
        region = region || 'US';

        $.ajax({
            url: '/mapData/' + region
        }).success(function (response) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response);

            var options = {
                region: region,
                displayMode: 'markers',
                colorAxis: {colors: ['blue', 'red']},
                resolution: 'provinces'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_' + region.toLowerCase()));
            console.log('Drawing chart for ' + region + ' with ', data);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    }
```

Comment: first, which chart library are you including, `loader.js` or `jsapi`?  do you call `google.setOnLoadCallback` more than once? any `$().ready` functions in play?  -- one option may be to draw both charts without markers, then load markers asynchronously and redraw as they come in.

Comment: @WhiteHat Didn't know there was more than one. I am including `jsapi`. I am calling `setOnLoadCallback` once. The on ready function does set some event listeners for UI elements.

Comment: all sounds fine, I would recommend using [`loader.js`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs), `jsapi` is considered "the old loader"  -- but probably won't have any impact here